# Cypress - How to run specific test case in different browser

Tags: reactjs, typescript, cypress

I have one file authentication.cy.ts where I am performing all the specs related to authentication.  I have a scenario where I want to log in user at the same time in a different browser.

I know we can directly give a browser option while running the cypress test. In my case, I can't give it because it should be ongoing. I have gone through this documentation https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/cross-browser-testing and didn't find anything similar.

My flow is like below

1. user logs in to chrome.
2. user performs some actions after login.
3. user tries to login in the firefox or any other browser.
4. user should get mail for verification OTP in firefox
5. user enters OTP and it should get login

Comment: This is a cypress trade-off..:( [Cypress Trade-offs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs#:~:text=You%20cannot%20use%20Cypress%20to,origin%20command.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are swapping browsers, and Cypress runs the app inside an `iframe` in a *particular* browser, one option is to use the [Module API](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/module-api) to perform two different browser tests in one sequence.

```js
// e2e-run-check-otp-after-authentication.js
const cypress = require('cypress')

cypress.run({
  spec: './cypress/e2e/examples/authentication.cy.js',
  browser: 'chrome',
})

cypress.run({
  spec: './cypress/e2e/examples/check-otp.cy.js',
  browser: 'firefox',
})
```

The above is a nodeJs script, by convention in the `scripts` folder of the project.

You call it from the command line like this

```js
node e2e-run-check-otp-after-authentication.js
```

Answer (score 0):

For your use case, it may be easier to switch sessions (or logout) within the test, rather than switching browsers. Your session management could include clearing cookies related to remembering prior users.

See the Cypress documentation here: https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Switching-sessions-inside-tests

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question properly. it is not about the session in the cypress. when the user tries to do login in to a different browser my backend triggers some validation. I want to test that. Switching browser is the only option to test this scenario as per my business logic

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I do not see support for this in Cypress. So to test what you want it may get complex. You could write a bash script to run two sets of Cypress tests back-to-back. Not sure if I can be of more help.

Answer (score 0):

Cypress indeed doesn't support such stuff and it would be very resource-intensive (considering Cypress already is very resource intensive)
What you might try is launching a puppeteer/playwright process via `cy.task`, it can be safely integrated in your config file just for this sake